# C++/OpenGL - Starting a new project

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm starting a new project using C++ and OpenGL to make a simple game and to teach myself OpenGL. I do not want to use GLUT, and would rather use SDL for making windows and such. I'm having a lot of weird trouble with the Makefile, however. Currently, when I type make, I get this response when I include `$(LFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)` in my G++ commands:

```
g++-5 tetris.o -o tetris -std=c++14
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in tetris.o
  "_SDL_GL_CreateContext", referenced from:
      _main in tetris.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in tetris.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      game_loop(SDL_Window*)     in tetris.o
  "_glewGetErrorString", referenced from:
      _main in tetris.o
  "_glewInit", referenced from:
      _main in tetris.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tetris] Error 1
```

and this response when I do not:

```
g++-5 -Wall  -framework SDL2 tetris.o -o tetris -std=c++14
ld: framework not found SDL2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tetris] Error 1
```

Here is my new Makefile:

```
CC = g++-5
CFLAGS = -Wall -c -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LFLAGS = -Wall 
LDFLAGS = -framework SDL2
LDLIBS= -lSDL2 -lglew -lGL
INCLUDES = -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/
STD = -std=c++14

all: tetris

tetris: tetris.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) tetris.o -o tetris $(STD)

tetris.o: tetris.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ tetris.cpp $(STD)

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm tetris *.o
```

And the headers part of my .cpp file:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Do you have a 32 bit architecture CPU or a 64 bit?

Comment: 64-bit OS X El Capitan. Just kinda wondering what linking needs to be done in the makefile to make all this weirdness go away. It doesn't help that all the functions in OpenGL tutorials are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need to add

```
LDFLAGS = -framework GLUT
```

to your Makefile

Comment: I think that fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @IanH  try to change -LGLEW to -lglew

Comment: INCLUDES = -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/

Comment: add this line to your Makefile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124138/discussion-between-antonsavich-and-ian-h).

Comment: This adds the GLUT framework, which the question poster said they didn't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just use freeglut, you don't need to use SDL so that you can get started with OpenGL.

Comment: How would I do this. I want to be able to open a window and do stuff inside said window.

Comment: You create a child window inside the main window, will put your user interface in the main window, use the child window for OpenGL rendering